# HTTP Error 500 - The FastCGI Process Exited Unexpectedly

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have IIS manager 7.5 and installed PHP 5.6 using Web Platform Installer, as well as Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86). But when I typed in http://localhost/Phpinfo.php, I got 500 internal server error ../php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly. I looked at the php error log but got nothing in it. I've looked at other similar posts and tried to do something with the PHP manager and FastCGI but none of them worked for me. I would be very much appreciated if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!!

[php manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM3CT.png)

Comment: do you see any thing in the PHP error log? , you can see the location of the log file in the php manager ,

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just attached the log but did not see anything useful or I just dont understood

Comment: this is the IIS log, you should also have a PHP log. you can find the location of the log file in PHP manager or in the php.ini file, I think that the default location is in C:\windows\tmp

Comment: I checked php manager and it said File "C:\Windows\temp\PHP56_errors.log" does not exist. But the path was set in php.init...

Comment: it could be a permission problem, try changing the file location to somewhere you know you have write permission and in PHP manager configure error reporting  and set it to  development machine

Comment: I have changed the location of my php error log and ran the phpinfo.php again. But when I checked the log within php manager, it was blank. Attached the php manager setting

Comment: Run `php-cgi.exe` at command prompt, and usually it tells what is the error.

Answer (score -1):

downloading the php 5 for iis express resolve the issue for me .